# Django cannot import app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Following the [django-rest tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)

app/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from app.abbr import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Directory structure:

[image]

Error:

> File "..../app/app/urls.py", line 3, in 
>      from app.abbr import views
>   ImportError: No module named 'app.abbr'

So, sigh...

Comment: Please follow step by step, word by word the tutorial before doing anything to tune it (changing the layout, the application names and co). Once you've done it, you'll be able to redo with some changes. Don't stack complexity.

Answer (score 6):

It would have been useful if you pointed to the tutorial that showed you to do this.

You should not import from `app`; that refers to the inner directory containing your urls.py. Just import from `abbr`.

```
from abbr import views
```

Comment: Added link. Your solution seems to work; do you mind looking at the tutorial and mention why they have it like that? They explicitly create a `tutorial` project and then a `quickstart` app and reference it in the `urls.py` like I did. Can their solution possibly work?

Comment: I don't know python internals in the deep level, but my guess that since you have to app modules, python supposes that you trying to import app from the closest module (parent of urls.py). https://github.com/tomchristie/rest-framework-tutorial
Note, that they doing 
`mkdir tutorial` and `cd tutorial`, but after that they making `cd tutorial` one more time.

Answer (score 0):

And what if you change import like this?
`from app.app.abbr import views`?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'app.app'`

Comment: Looks like your manage.py is placed in app.app module (if I got your screen right). Are you sure that it shouwld be placed there and not in first `app`?
In the attached to mentioned tutorial repo https://github.com/tomchristie/rest-framework-tutorial manage.py placed in the root of the directory.

Comment: I see they use `django-admin.py` to create the app and I used `manage.py`. Is there any difference?

Comment: As I mentioned above, they have another project structure.  that they doing `mkdir tutorial` and `cd tutorial`, but after that they making `cd tutorial` ome more time. It matches with their github repo structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are using **django 1.9** +

Try this

```
from . import views
```

Answer (score 0):

The root directory folder named App in your case is named after your project name by default when you start a new project via the django-admin startproject command.

you can rename your root directory folder to whatever you want and it won't affect your project.

when in your code are importing from app, it is actually looking inside the 'app' folder containig the 'settings.py' file.

the [django-rest tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) you are following contains an error when they are doing `from tutorial.quickstart import views` which should be `from quickstart import views`

so the same goes for you, you should do `from abbr import views`